# How to pull AD user email then pass it to Function to send email using that ADuser email

Tags: windows, powershell, foreach

Im wanting to Get all users from a security group and pull their email. Once I get their email, I then want to pass that list of email addresses to a function (ideally a for loop) to send a email to all the users in that security group. Any help is appreciated.

```
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'IS-Test-GRP' -Recursive |
  Select-Object -Unique | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | Select-Object Mail

Foreach($user in $users)
{
Send-MailMessage -From joetest@mail.com -To $user.mail -Subject 'Migrating 
File Share' -Body 'Hello All, 
I will be migrating the share folder <   > from app02 to app03. Once 
completed I will email all users the new file path location to access the 
share. If you will be needing help creating a new shortcut, please contact 
the help desk. Any issues or questions, please let me know.  -Thank you' - 
SmtpServer 'mail.server.com'
}
```

Comment: So which one is failing - the user enumeration, or the mail sending? Insert `$user.mail` into your Foreach so that you see that you're getting the right e-mails. Also, is mail.server.com your *real* server name, or a placeholder for SO?

Comment: place holder. And youre referring to < Foreach($user.mail in $users) >

Comment: I suggest that you output the value of $user.mail as the first line of the loop body. A line with nothing but a variable name will print that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
$users = $(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'IS-Test-GRP' -Recursive | Select- 
Object -Unique | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail).Mail
```

The only problem I see is `$users` will be a collection of objects. When you enumerate the collection, I don't see you specifying, which property is/has the `Mail`.